# Check through an array and identify matching numbers

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am working on a scratch card game where by a user purchases a scratch card from me/my store and can then redeem said card by scratching off numbers and matching 3 pictures to win a prize

Like physical scratch cards I want the prizes to be pre configured so that I know when a prize will be won, but obviously the users dont, this is so I can limit the prizes, so it is not true random, but will be random in terms of who wins the prize..

I know how I will setup the prizes but I need to check each data value in an array to ensure that there is not 3 matching numbers, unless they have actually won..

So far I have this (I will neaten it up and shorten the code down soon)

```
$numbers = array(
    0 => rand(0,9),
    1 => rand(0,9),
    2 => rand(0,9),
    3 => rand(0,9),
    4 => rand(0,9),
    5 => rand(0,9),
    6 => rand(0,9),
    7 => rand(0,9),
    8 => rand(0,9)
    );
```

Which just randomly generates 9 numbers and

```
echo "<table>";
    $i=0;
    for($x=0;$x<3;$x++){
    echo "<tr>";
       for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
           echo "<td>" . $numbers[$i] . "</td>";
           $i++;
       }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Sorts them into a 3x3 table

I know there is the command in_array() which will sort through the array looking for certain values but I dont want to run an endless loop checking each value to see if I get a match, because it's labor intensive and would be messy as well.

I'm looking for a suggestion anyone might have so I can sort through the array and see if any 3 numbers exist, if they do, and they're not suppost to (ie the user hasn't actually won a prize) then one should be changed to a new number.

So thank you in advance for your help guys I look forward to your suggestions

Luke

****** EDIT ********

+More info

To pick the winners I will use a database query such as this

```
$stock = $conn -> query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM codes WHERE Available = 1 AND 0 = FLOOR(RAND()*Chance) ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Each code will have a set chance to win and if it matches up it will be shown, depending on the code won a certain prize will show

```
$stock = $conn -> query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM codes WHERE Available = 1 AND Win = 1);
```

'Win' will be a table in the database which each time someone plays the game it goes down by 1

So each code will have the table Win which when it hits 1 it will pop out the in the next game

These are two ways I can think of doing it which I think will work, both ways roughly allow me to control when and if someone wins but the second solution is obviously a more accurate way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about not changing a number if a triple one occurs, but preventing a triple one occurs.

```
function createScratchRange()
{
    $result = array();
    $options = array_merge(range(0,9), range(0,9));

    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
    {
        $key =  array_rand($options, 1);
        $result[] = $options[$key];
        unset($options[$key]);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and you might want to be able to create winners:

```
function createWinner()
{
    $winningNumber = rand(0,9);

    $result = array();
    $possibleNumbers = range(0,9);
    unset($possibleNumbers[$winningNumber]);
    $options = array_merge($possibleNumbers,$possibleNumbers);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
    {
        $key =  array_rand($options, 1);
        $result[] = $options[$key];
        unset($options[$key]);
    }

    // looks random now.. but no winning numbers... Lets just stick them in there.
    $keys = array_rand($result, 3);
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        $result[$key] = $winningNumber;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and for testing:

```
var_dump(createScratchRange());  // this will never give 3 identical numbers in the array.
var_dump(createWinner());  // this will ALWAYS give 3 identical numbers, but never 2 sets of 3 identical numbers
```

Comment: Ideally this needs to work for 3 numbers, 2 matching is fine but 3 matching numbers imply's the person has won, as the chance of winning a prize is not set by php rather it is set as a database query I dont need to worry about how many doubles there are I just need it to mask if 3 numbers match and they're not supposed to. Thank you for your reply though, it's a little over my head but I think i understand the gist of what it would achieve

Comment: Sorry, it is about triples, i wrote the comment wrong. the first function gives 9 random numbers with max 2 the same and the second function will give 9 random numbers but always with 3 identical (but never 2 sets of 3 identical).
so it will not give 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3. just copy paste this and try it out

Comment: Ahh I see thank you! I have just tested out the createStratchRange function and it looks like it works great. With the createWinner function can I replace the randomly generated number with one taken from the database so $winningNumber = $_SESSION['itemid'] or something similar to that so the winning number corresponds to the prize won?

Comment: Just tested out the createWinner function and like predicted it works great. Thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it. Luke

Comment: I don't know if you tried it already, but yes you can replace the random number with something like session. However i would pass it through an argument to keep the code clean.